# Get image file name from PictureBox control

Tags: vb.net, image, title, picturebox

I have an image in a folder which I am able to display onto a PictureBox in the following manner:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Nothing 'Clearing PictureBox1 
Dim bmPhotos as new Bitmap("C:\Photos\ImageName.gif")
PictureBox1.Image = bmPhotos
```

I would like to obtain additional information about the image. Specifically the image Title. Is that possible to do in .Net?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the image metadata such as Title, Author, Camera Make, Model, etc., They are stored in the Image Header as EXIF.

They can be retrieved by using [PropertyItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Every Property Tag is identified by a hexadecimal value and you can find them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534418%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
'Create an Image object. 
Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Ashish\apple.jpg")

'Get the PropertyItems property from image.
Dim propItems As PropertyItem() = img.PropertyItems

Dim encoding As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()

Dim title As String = encoding.GetString(propItems(0).Value)
Dim manufacturer As String = encoding.GetString(propItems(1).Value)
```

A very simple implementation to read EXIF metadata is [available here](https://kellyschronicles.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/get-or-write-image-metadata-with-vb-net/).

[image]

Comment: Ashish, I looped through all elements of propItems and the Type was the sixth element. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can get additional information using **System.IO.Path** and **System.IO.File** like these:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName("ImagePathHere")
System.IO.Path.GetExtension("ImagePathHere")
System.IO.File.GetCreationTime("ImagePathHere")
System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime("ImagePathHere")
```

Just explore it and you can get more details about your file.

Answer (score 0):

[`Path.GetFileName Method (String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx): Returns the file name and extension of the specified path string.

[`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method (String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx): Returns the file name of the specified path string without the extension.

```
 If PictureBox1.Location.ToString <> String.Empty Then
     Dim image_title, image_title1 As String
     'To get file name with extension : output=ImageName.gif
     image_title = Path.GetFileName(picImage.ImageLocation)

     'To get file name without extension : output=ImageName
     image_title1 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(picImage.ImageLocation)
 End If
```